# Database archive technique with 2 databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database which contains data for events. For every event database size increases by 1 GB.

I have planned to create a separate database for archive. After completing each event, I plan to move that data to the archive database using a stored procedure.

I have already added many indexes on database to improve speed.

So is this good technique or is there any better idea to improve the speed on database ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need to copy/move DB and not create new DB and keep previous as archive? How many events are created in 1 year?

Comment: In 1 year 30 to 40 event is created also old event data is important for history

Comment: And what is the data in DB - many records or big objects?

Comment: Yes there are many table and many records

Comment: Is it necessary to run "cross-query", i.e. query whose results come from 2+ events? Or all history accesses will be limited to specific event-period.

Comment: Yes It require for check the history of person and on that base current event         seat will get reserved.